# Fetching data from Chrome Developer Tool for Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have been trying to search for a way to fetch and store the rendering and style information of a webpage from the Chrome Developer Tool to be used in my extension. I looked into the Chrome Devtool API and Debugger API with no luck. Does Chrome provide a way for developers to log its rendering data? Thank you for your help.

Comment: As is, "rendering and style information of a webpage" is too broad a description. Also, it would help if you told in more detail what didn't work out with `devtools`/`debugger` API - they both can be used to some degree.

Comment: Thank you for your response. By "rendering and style information", I mean  information such as the element's css rules, computed style, box dimension, etc. These information are provided in the style tab of the Chrome Developer Tool. So I have been looking into the API for a way to log these information provided. Sorry I am still new to developing Chrome extension.

Comment: How about persisting the data in `storage` first for your extension to use? There doesn't seem to have a DevTool to Extension communication, though DevTool can [communicate between extension components](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools#solutions) (injecting Content Scripts) a limitation of Content Script is it cannot use variables or functions of other content scripts. Persisting it to storage first can mitigate the limitation and be able to communicate the DevTool and Extension.